# Data isn't saving in SQL Server (ASP.NET)

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net, sql-server, ado.net

The data isn't saving in the database and I really don't know why.

The IDs are correctly placed and the button has  `OnClick="Button1_Click"`.

When I moved the `Response.Write("<script>alert('Testing');</script>");` in the `try` block it didn't appear on the screen, no matter if I placed it in the `if()` or after it.

Here is my aspx.cs:

```
public partial class usersignup : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    string strcon = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["con"].ConnectionString;

    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }

    // sing up button is clicked (connecting with the DB
    protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
      //Response.Write("<script>alert('Testing');</script>");

        try
        {
            SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(strcon);
            if (con.State == ConnectionState.Closed)
            {
                con.Open();                    
            }

            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("INSERT INTO member_master_tbl(first_name, birthday, last_name, email, country, city, gender, address, username, password) " +
                " values(@first_name, @birthday, @last_name, @email, @country, @city, @gender, @address, @username, @password)", con);

            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@first_name", TextBox1.Text.Trim());
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@birthday", TextBox2.Text.Trim());
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@last_name", TextBox3.Text.Trim());
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@email", TextBox4.Text.Trim());
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@country", DropDownList1.SelectedItem.Value);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@city", TextBox6.Text.Trim());
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@gender", DropDownList2.SelectedItem.Value);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@address", TextBox5.Text.Trim());
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@username", TextBox7.Text.Trim());
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@password", TextBox8.Text.Trim());
            //cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@account_status", "pending");

            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            con.Close();
            Response.Write("<script>alert('Sign Up Successful. Go to User Login to Login');</script>");
        } 
        catch(Exception ex)
        {
            Response.Write("<script>alert('" + ex.Message + "');</script>");
        }
    }
}
```

And here is how the database looks like:

```
SELECT TOP (1000) [first_name]
      ,[birthday]
      ,[last_name]
      ,[email]
      ,[country]
      ,[city]
      ,[gender]
      ,[address]
      ,[username]
      ,[password]
  FROM [elibraryDB].[dbo].[member_master_tbl]
```

Comment: Inside your code, don't check connection state, just open it always. Consider using `using` block also.

Comment: Hi, I tried just opening the connection and it still didn't work.

Comment: Step through your code with the debugger one line at a time, so you can see what is really happening

Comment: are you getting exception?

Comment: I don't think the try block is being executed

Comment: I am not getting any exceptions nor am I getting "successful"

Comment: if the try block isn't being executed (I assume you have checked this with the debugger as I mentioned?? You didn't really make clear.), have you put a breakpoint on the line inside the "catch" block instead? If _none_ of it is being executed then this most likely indicates that your button click event isn't wired up properly.

Comment: Dan Guzman says: ["AddWithValue is Evil"](http://www.dbdelta.com/addwithvalue-is-evil/) - please read the article and stop using it!

Comment: did button click fire? if this is not fired event might be not registered

Comment: The try block is now working somehow but the data is still not being saved and there are no exceptions...

Comment: The button works but the data doesn't get saved

Comment: This looks dangerous: `cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@password", TextBox8.Text.Trim());`. You should not store the plain text password!

Comment: I agree with you, user1429080. I am following a tutorial, it was not my idea to use this.

Comment: GUYS, I FIXED IT! :D

Comment: if you found a solution then please post your fix in the Answers section below so that others may benefit from it in future (and you can receive upvote points if it's useful to people). Thanks